# Remove date form permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to link some titles on homepage in wordpress.
And I have this code:

```
<?php
@preg_match("/link=\"(.*?)\"/is", $post->post_content, $_tmp);
<h3><a href="<?php echo $_tmp[1]; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
?>
```

So with this, link looks like:
http://example.com/2016/03/16/tsar-ivan-terrible-vodka/

I want to change pattern, to remove date from link.
So the filnal link will be:
http://example.com/tsar-ivan-terrible-vodka/

Can anybody help?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just change it under Settings > Permalinks?

Comment: Yes I change it. Because that I have this problem.

Comment: without your regex, why you just change `echo $_tmp[1];` with `the_permalink();`?

Answer (score 1):

you doesnt need any preg_match function to do this

> goto admin>>setting>>permalinks  on common setting Select "Post name" instead of "day and name"

then you will get the  url as you need http://example.com/tsar-ivan-terrible-vodka/

to get the post url

```
<?php get_post_permalink(post_id); ?>
```